# Losing items in Coldfusion arrays

Tags: coldfusion, memcached, spymemcached

This is driving me crazy. We have tried to build a CF memcached wrapper. We have a memcached.cfc component like this:

```
<cfset this.m = arraynew(1)>

<cffunction name="init" access="public" output="false">
    <cfif not isdefined("application.memcached")
    ....
            <cfscript>
            setup();
                </cfscript>
         ...
            <cfset application.memcached = this>
          </cfif>
   <cfreturn application.memcached>
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="setup" access="private" output="false">
    <cftry>
        <cfset this.m = arraynew(1)>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#this.poolSize#" index="i">
            <cfset this.m[i] = createClient()>
        </cfloop>
        <cflog application="no" file="memcached" text="Successfully set up #this.poolSize# new memcache clients">
        <cfcatch>
            <cflog application="no" file="memcached" text="Exception in setup() while setting up the pool: type: #cfcatch.type#, message: #cfcatch.message#, detail: #cfcatch.detail#">
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="createClient" access="private" output="false">
    <cfset var AU = createObject("java", "net.spy.memcached.AddrUtil").init()>
    <cfset var c = createObject("java", "net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient").init(AU.getAddresses("127.0.0.1:11211"))>
    <cfreturn c>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getCache" access="public" returntype="any" output="false">
    <cfset idx = ceiling(rand() * 20)>
    <cfreturn application.memcached.m[idx]>
</cffunction>
```

The weird thing is that after running for 30 minutes or so, the getCache starts failing says that there is no item in the application.memcached.m array at position idx.

How could this be happening? Are CF arrays using weak references or something? Surely once the array is populated with 20 clients the array should stay full always?

Each new client spawns a new thread so once we lose the reference to the client there is now way to shut it down and that thread lives there forever taking memory. Please, what am i missing?

Comment: btw, it was a long time I last implemented a cfc.. but I think you can call a function with <cfset setup() />. I'm not sure though :)

Comment: You need to varscope 'i' in your setup function and 'idx' in your getCache function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your application scope gets deleted. You should specify a proper timeout for that. You should also log this whether OnApplication gets called or not for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that Application scope existed until Coldfusion was restarted :( I'll look into that!

Comment: oh ok.. so you should definately look into Application.cfc. You can do some interesting stuff with it..

Answer (score 1):

When does this memcached CFC get used?  Every request?  The lack of var scoping on the 'i' and 'idx' variables could **well** have something to do with it.  Here's a couple of articles I wrote that do a simple demonstration of why this is essential.

http://duncan99.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/the-importance-of-var-scoping/

http://duncan99.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/the-importance-of-var-scoping-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably something fairly simple - the fact that any instantiation of this class will immediately invalidate the array in the application scope makes this a fairly troublesome class to manage.  In addition, while the spy memcached driver itself behaves as a singleton, and the array (java.util.vector) is thread-safe, nothing else about this implementation is - not the app scope, definitely not the cfc instance.

Assuming you can eliminate an out of bounds value for idx in the getCache() function (which I assume you already did, if not, throw a try/catch block in the function and report what idx is when the exception is thrown), you can remedy the symptoms without actually addressing the cause by using exclusive cflocks with the same name around the constructor and the getCache() method.  This way even if you have random instantiations of your class, you won't ever be able to blow the array out while something is trying to access it, and you won't be able to attempt to access it while it's being re-created.  This is not an optimal solution at all, and if you experience high concurrency you will notice a slight elevation in response times (fairly negligible, but depending on how many requests/sec you serve, it can definitely have an impact on max throughput.